# How to allow CORS on wordpress?

Tags: android, wordpress, cors, content-management-system

I'm working on an android application that opens an instance of a wordpress website in a webview. The website loads fine until I try to login. When I login with my credentials the website crashes. In the logs I'm getting an error saying that I need to enable cross origin resource sharing on the wordpress website. The wordpress website is hosted by wordpress. I tried going into the wp-admin panel to enable it. I tried doing it through a plugin. I  also tried to edit the .php files to allow cross origin sharing but it seems that the issue is at the server level where the wordpress is hosting the website and the server itself is not allowing me to do that. Could it be that since it may be shared vps and that's why they can't allow it for security reasons? How can I confirm if that is the case?  Has anyone tried to setup a webview for a wordpress website in their android application, and if yes then how should I resolve this issue? The android application is developed in native android.

Expected to be able to login into the wordpress website that is being displayed in a webview inside the android application. Right now the website crashes and brings me back to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function initCors( $value ) {
  $origin = get_http_origin();
  $allowed_origins = [ 'site1.example.com', 'site2.example.com', 'localhost:3000' ];

  if ( $origin && in_array( $origin, $allowed_origins ) ) {
    header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . esc_url_raw( $origin ) );
    header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET' );
    header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );
  }

  return $value;
}
```